# Python pandas reading file error: ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error:

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to read this file: https://ufile.io/7orq1ch4

```
result = pd.read_table('Testdata2.txt' , decimal = ',')
print(result)
```

but the following error occurs

> File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 2132, in
>   pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error
>
> ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line
>   4, saw 11

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you done any debugging?

Comment: link to the file is dead

Answer (score 1):

try `pd.read_csv('Testdata2.txt', decimal = ',')` instead of `pd.read_table`

Answer (score 1):

If you get rid of the first 3 lines of `testdata2.txt` and try to load with

```
df = pd.read_table('testdata2.txt', sep='\t', decimal=',')
print(df)
```

You get:

```
   Unnamed: 0 Unnamed: 1    Name 1  ...     Name 7     Name 8  Unnamed: 10
0     Value 1     Nr : 1  8681.874  ...  10642.554  10052.674          NaN
1      [Unit]     Nr : 2  8845.703  ...   5071.242   8091.932          NaN
2         NaN     Nr : 3  8776.430  ...   5574.648   6134.294          NaN
3         NaN     Nr : 4  8908.256  ...   5540.018   7125.733          NaN
4         NaN     Nr : 5  8569.452  ...   4841.109   7034.558          NaN
5         NaN     Nr : 6  8903.974  ...   4944.648   6724.618          NaN
6         NaN     Nr : 7  8678.188  ...   4838.960   6583.222          NaN
7         NaN     Nr : 8  8721.757  ...   5345.413   5829.537          NaN
8         NaN     Nr : 9  8792.308  ...   5177.859   6244.115          NaN
9         NaN    Nr : 10  8604.521  ...   4683.798   6081.107          NaN
10        NaN    Nr : 11  8945.809  ...   5888.516   6463.932          NaN
11        NaN    Nr : 12  8668.207  ...        NaN        NaN          NaN
12        NaN    Nr : 13  8865.165  ...        NaN        NaN          NaN
13        NaN    Nr : 14  8973.844  ...        NaN        NaN          NaN
14        NaN    Nr : 15  8645.630  ...        NaN        NaN          NaN
15        NaN    Nr : 16  8915.668  ...        NaN        NaN          NaN
16        NaN    Nr : 17  8931.855  ...        NaN        NaN          NaN
17        NaN    Nr : 18  9136.108  ...        NaN        NaN          NaN
18        NaN    Nr : 19  8605.307  ...        NaN        NaN          NaN
19        NaN    Nr : 20  8886.002  ...        NaN        NaN          NaN
20        NaN    Nr : 21  8729.902  ...        NaN        NaN          NaN
21        NaN    Nr : 22  8781.786  ...        NaN        NaN          NaN
22        NaN    Nr : 23  8760.748  ...        NaN        NaN          NaN
23        NaN    Nr : 24  9281.921  ...        NaN        NaN          NaN
24        NaN    Nr : 25  8842.649  ...        NaN        NaN          NaN
25        NaN       Mean  8818.123  ...   5686.251   6942.339          NaN
26    Value 2     Nr : 1   804.036  ...    985.616    930.987          NaN
27     [Unit]     Nr : 2   819.208  ...    469.652    749.401          NaN
28        NaN     Nr : 3   812.793  ...    516.273    568.102          NaN
29        NaN     Nr : 4   825.001  ...    513.066    659.921          NaN
30        NaN     Nr : 5   793.625  ...    448.339    651.477          NaN
31        NaN     Nr : 6   824.605  ...    457.928    622.773          NaN
[truncated]
```

Depending on what you are doing, I suggest you to fill the NaN values using:

```
df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

Bye!

Comment: Thanks, the following works fine:

`df=pd.read_table('testdata2.txt' , decimal = ',' , skiprows=3 , encoding =  'unicode_escape')`